# How can you expect a method to be invoked multiple times with different arguments

Tags: ruby, minitest

I want to be able to expect multiple invocations of the same method with different arguments in Minitest.

Imagine the method and class definition:

```rb
class TicketSeller
  def complete
    EventHandler.trigger(:payment_processed)
    EventHandler.trigger(:ticket_sold)
  end
end
```

I would expect the following test to pass:

```rb
test "triggers events :payment_processed and :ticket_sold" do
  # set up expectations
  EventHandler.expects(:trigger).with(:payment_processed)
  EventHandler.expects(:trigger).with(:ticket_sold)

  # invoke method
  TicketSeller.new.complete
end
```

Instead, I get an error like:

```
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-:payment_processed
+:ticket_sold
```